# Dried out Crassula Tetragona

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, succulents

My crassula tetragona has dried out, it lives on the windowsill and is watered once a week. It’s never been green

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say the plant doesn't show signs of life to provide hope for rejuvenation. Too much water (perhaps) or too little water, a fixed schedule ignores the plant's actual needs.